# Read JSON returned by AJAX call

Tags: jquery, json, response

I am new to AJAX. I am submitting my form data into a end point using AJAX. The endpoint is returning a json string with some response data. I tried many things but wasn;t able to read the JSON.

I can parse the JSON. At this point, I want to figure out how I can read the JSON returned by the end point.

My code so that posts to the end pint.

```
$('.ent-lead-form form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;

        if($(this).find('.err').length == 0){
            $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="form-mask"></div>');

            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data){

                    var data = JSON.parse(json);
                    alert(data);

                    // redirect to success or show thank you
                    if( $(form).find('input[name=successurl]').length == 1 ){
                        window.location = $(form).find('input[name=successurl]').val();
                    } else {
                        $(form).parent().prepend('<div class="confirm-mask">Thank you for your submission.</div>');
                    }

                    // cleanup
                    $('.form-mask').remove();

                },
                error: function(data){
                    // show error
                    $(form).parent().prepend('<div class="confirm-mask">There was an error processing your request.  Please reload the page and try again.</div>');
                    $('.form-mask').remove();

                }
            });


       }
});
```

Comment: What's the structure of the JSON response? What do you want do with it?

Comment: You're calling `JSON.parse(json)`, but there's no `json` variable. Did you mean to use `function(json)`?

Comment: You can use `dataType: 'json'` and `$.ajax` will parse the JSON automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error here ..

```
 success: function(data){

                    var data = JSON.parse(json);
                    alert(data);
```

**Change this to**

```
success: function(jsondata){

                    var data = JSON.parse(jsondata);
                    console.log(data);
```

Your "data" will be an object. You can get to your values wuith teh dot notation

```
data.value
```

To add a comment to this:
It is better to start using `.done()`

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/